# How to use ruby to extract a field

Tags: ruby, split

I am trying write a ruby program that will open a file, extract the 15th field delineated by `"|"`, and print that to the screen. I need to test it by doing the following (example):

```
cat /directory name/directory name/filename.rrf | less
```

and have the 15th field of each line of that file show up on the screen. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not much. I'm already stuck on trying to open a file from a different directory. I think i need to do something like filename.each do |line| and then a split command somewhere to denote that I want to keep only the fifteenth field. However, I'm stuck on even trying to access this file if it is buried in a few other directories. Apologies for my ignorance - I have never programmed before!

Comment: It is not clear how your test works. Where in the code do you have a ruby command?

Comment: I need to write a ruby program that will allow me to open a file, cut out only the 15th field of each line in that file, and print that to the screen.

Answer (score 4):

```
File.open(filename).each do |line|
  puts line.split('|')[14]
end
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need ruby for this.

```
echo "aaa,bbb,ccc" | cut -d ',' -f 2
# bbb
```

If you decide to use ruby, you can split a string like this:

```
"aaa,bbb,ccc".split(",")[1]
# bbb
```

You can also check out stdlib's [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html).  See the `:col_sep` option.

Comment: Unfortunately I am required to use ruby for this exercise. I think I understand the split command, but I'm confused on where to put it in relation to opening a file and telling it split each line in the file (it is a VERY large file).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Unix linebreaks (`\n`), then the following should do it:

```
file = File.open("data", "r")  # input filename goes here
data = file.read
file.close
lines = data.split(/\n/)
lines.each { |line| 
  p line.split(/\|/)[14]
}
```

For simplicity, the above code doesn't validate if there are actually at least 15 fields in each line.

Comment: Does the file name go in the ( )? what does the "r" denote?

Comment: The above code reads a file named `data`. Simply replace the `"data"` in the first line with the desired filename, e.g. `"mydata.dat"`. The `"r"` means *open the file in read-mode* (we're reading the file, and not writing into it).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Rachael. By the way, the StackOverflow way to say *it worked for me* is to accept the answer (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers).